# Can we refer to every ancient document as "scripture"?

Tags: discussion

I am having a problem with nomenclature when asking questions.

What is the correct word to use when referring to Hinduism related documents before book publishing began? Is it `scripture`?

Are there any documents that can NOT be referred as a scripture, but still are very old?

Comment: If this is not about scripture *tag*, I think it is fine to ask on main site.

Comment: @Pandya I'm not sure actually. Does `scripture` tag mean something different from `scripture` word when used by historians?